# Using Spark on Dataproc, how to write to GCS separately from each partition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

Using Spark on GCP Dataproc, I successfuly write an entire RDD to GCS like so:

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"gs://$path")
```

The products are files for each partition in the same path.

How do I write files for each partition (with a unique path based on information from the partition)

Below is an invented non working wishful code example

```
    rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
      (i, partition) =>{

        partition.write(path = s"gs://partition_$i", data = partition_specific_data)
      }
    )
```

when I call the function below from within the partition on my mac it writes to local disk, on Dataproc I get an error not recognizing the gs as a valid path.

```
def writeLocally(filePath: String, data: Array[Byte], errorMessage: String): Unit = {

println("Juicy Platform")

val path = new Path(filePath)

var ofos: Option[FSDataOutputStream] = null

try {

  println(s"\nTrying to write to $filePath\n")

  val conf = new Configuration()

  conf.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
  conf.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")

  //      conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"))


  println(conf.toString)

  val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)

  val fos = fs.create(path)
  ofos = Option(fos)

  fos.write(data)

  println(s"\nWrote to $filePath\n")
}
catch {
  case e: Exception =>

    logError(errorMessage, s"Exception occurred writing to GCS:\n${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)}")
}
finally {
  ofos match {
    case Some(i) => i.close()
    case _ =>
  }
}
  }
```

This is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: gs://path/myFile.json, expected: hdfs://cluster-95cf-m
```

Comment: Are you executing your code inside Dataproc cluster? By default it has a [connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/install-storage-connector) that enables you to access GCS. If not, you have to install it.

Comment: Yes I am and it works on the RDD level. I need a way to write within each partition.

Answer (score 3):

If running on a Dataproc cluster, you shouldn't need to explicitly populate "fs.gs.impl" in the Configuration; a `new Configuration()` should already contain the necessary mappings.

The main problem here is that `val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)` is using the `fs.defaultFS` property of the conf; it has no way of knowing whether you wanted to get a FileSystem instance specific to HDFS or to GCS. In general, In Hadoop and Spark, a `FileSystem` instance is fundamentally tied to a single URL `scheme`; you need to fetch a scheme-specific instance for each different scheme, such as `hdfs://` or `gs://` or `s3://`.

The simplest fix to your problem is to always use [Path.getFileSystem(Configuration)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html#getFileSystem(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)) as opposed to `FileSystem.get(Configuration)`. And make sure your `path` is fully-qualified with the scheme:

```
...
val path = "gs://bucket/foo/data"
val fs = path.getFileSystem(conf)

val fos = fs.create(path)
ofos = Option(fos)

fos.write(data)
...
```

Comment: For me in Dataproc its creating folder but not writing file content and not throwing error also

Comment: Are you successfully calling fos.close() after writing your data? In GCS the data doesn't show up at all until you close() the stream to finalize the output.

Comment: Hey @Dennis Huo Thanks was  I was closing fs not fos